# What does the "+"-sign in the duration column of the last command in OS X terminal mean?

Tags: authentication, terminal, osx-elcapitan, tty

I am running `last` to check my kids computer usage and I am getting output like this:

```
Ruben     console   Wed Mar 22 09:17 - crash  (02:17)
Ruben     console   Tue Mar 14 15:56 - crash (6+06:52)
Ruben     console   Sat Mar  4 12:08 - crash (1+04:48)
Ruben     console   Tue Feb 28 16:24 - crash (3+01:48)
Ruben     console   Mon Feb 13 06:47 - crash  (10:39)
Ruben     console   Tue Jan 31 16:27 - crash  (01:16)
```

If I understand things correctly, the first line describes a 2 minutes, 17 seconds session. How do I read the following, though? What does `(6+06:52)` mean?